# Adding a document to the index in SOLR: Document contains at least one immense term

Tags: solr

I am adding (by a Java program) for indexing, a document in SOLR index, but after `add(inputDoc)` method there is an exception. The log in solr web interface contains the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="text" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[99, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 105, 110, 97, 32, 105, 110, 102, 111, 114, 109, 97, 122, 105, 111, 110, 105, 32, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 111, 32]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 226781
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:687)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:359)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:318)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:239)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:457)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1511)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:164)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash$MaxBytesLengthExceededException: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 226781
    at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:284)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.add(TermsHashPerField.java:151)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:663)
    ... 47 more
```

Please what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem as yours, finally I solved my problem. Please check the type of your "text" field, I suspect it must be "strings".

You can find it in the **managed-schema** of the core:

```
<field name="text" type="strings"/>
```

Or you can go to Solr Admin, access: http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/schema/fieldtypes?wt=json and then search for "text", if it is something like the follow, you know you defined your "text" field as strings type:

```
  {
  "name":"strings",
  "class":"solr.StrField",
  "multiValued":true,
  "sortMissingLast":true,
  "fields":["text"],
  "dynamicFields":["*_ss"]},
```

Then my solution works for you, you can change the type from "strings" to "text_general" in **managed-schema**. (make sure type of "text" in **schema.xml** is also "text_general")

```
   <field name="text" type="text_general">
```

This will solve your problem. strings is string field, but text_general is text field.

Comment: It's worked for me to replace all `strings` in `managed-schema` with `text_general`

Answer (score 5):

You probably met what is described in LUCENE-5472 [1]. There, Lucene throws an error if a term is too long. You could:

- use (in index analyzer), a LengthFilterFactory [2] in order to filter out those tokens that don't fall withing a requested length range
- use (in index analyzer), a TruncateTokenFilterFactory [3] for fixing the max length of indexed tokens
- use a custom UpdateRequestProcessor, but this actually depends on your context

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5472
[2] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory
[3] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory
[4] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor

Comment: [2] will only work with a low character limit under a 1000 it seems

[3] seems not to have this limit

But both are not working for string fields which limit custom analyzers.