# nutch indexing fails with io exception

Tags: indexing, nutch

Nutch indexing fails when I run the following command:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/test-tb/Downloads/apache-nutch-1.10# bin/nutch index mycrl/crawldb/ -dir mycrl/segments/
```

I am using nutch 1.10 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Error log details are:

```
2015-07-09 17:07:36,940 INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding    org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2015-07-09 17:07:36,970 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2015-07-09 17:07:37,030 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 100 documents
2015-07-09 17:07:37,136 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 100 documents
2015-07-09 17:07:37,166 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1383488781_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Not Found

Not Found

request: http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
at  org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:153)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:115)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:467)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:535)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)

2015-07-09 17:07:37,957 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:113)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:187)
```

Though I am not specifying a solr indexing option to nutch, this error is returned. Am I missing anything here? Your pointers will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are crawling and indexing data, then you should use `bin/crawl` as it is a better tool.

Second, from the stack trace, it is clear that you are not setting solr url correctly. In general, your solr url should be something like `http://domainname:port/solr/corename`

But, i see you have `localhost:8983/solr/update`. So, your url is missing the core name of solr. By default, it is collection1.

Comment: Thanks ameer but i am running into another strange problem. When I give the command " bin/crawl --index -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore urls/ ts/ 2", I am getting the exception " Bad Request  request: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update?wt=javabin&version=2
 at     org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)"
but when i run the commands with numrounds as 1, it is executed without   error.Any help?

Comment: Is solr running? Can you elaborate more about what you want to do.

Comment: Yes solr running. What I want to do is to test the nutch and solr to setup a simple search engine. To test it, I simply gave http://nutch.apache.org as the seed file and followed the instructions on the site. If this is succesful, I want to try the same for intranet urls.

Comment: Can you show me the error trace at nutch/logs/hadoop.log or solr logs. I think you not have copied the schema file from nutch/conf/schema.xml to solr/collection1/schema.xml

Comment: Thanks Ameer .. I copied the schema.xml to solr/corename/conf/ directory .. still the same problem .. but i checked the solr log and i found the below problem:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="content" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[65, 112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 32, 76, 117, 99, 101, 110, 101, 32, 45, 32, 87, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 65, 112, 97]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 33820

Comment: Have a look at this [related stack over flow question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445323/adding-a-document-to-the-index-in-solr-too-big-field-text). By the way, could you accept or upvote my answer if it was useful for you.